# What does this do and how in an array D[i].length

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of strings. In the nested loop under `j` I have `j < D[i].length`. I do get that the array size is 6, BUT how does `j` equal 6? At the first initial start i = 0 so I see it as `j < D[0].length`. Can someone please help me understand how `j` is assigned to `6`?

```
String [][] D = new String[5][6];

   for (int i = 0; i < D.length; i++) //Loads the array with o's to all indexes
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < D[i].length; j++)
      {
         D[i][j] = o;
      }
```

Comment: Please tag the language you are working with for more exposure and so readers know what language you are using.

Comment: well [6][6] will not do the justice but if let say we have [4][5] we would need to specify j<D[row].length because will be out of bounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j++` in the loop means that `j` increases by 1 each iteration. Since your stopping condition is `< D.length`, `j` will never reach `6`, since 6 is `D.length` and the loop will only iterate while `j < D.length`. The highest number `j` will reach is `5`.

Also remember array indices start at 0, so accessing the `index 5 (j = 5)` is actually accessing the 6th value in the array.

Declare the array like this `String [][] D = new String[6][6];` does not mean you can access index 6, it is just the size of the array, `available indices being 0,1,2,3,4,5`.

Idices for `String[][]D = new String[6][6]`

```
0,0  0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5

1,0  1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5

2,0  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5

3,0  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5

4,0  4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5

5,0  5,1  5,2  5,3  5,4  5,5
```

You can see that the 2D array has 6 rows and 6 columns, but the max index you can access is `5,5`

Edit: with OP edit

Idices for `String[][]D = new String[5][6]`

```
0,0  0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5

1,0  1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5

2,0  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5

3,0  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5

4,0  4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5
```

Comment: this String [][] D = new String[6][5]; will throw an error on leaving the j at j < D.length;

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at twoDimArray.main(twoDimArray.java:15)

Comment: Just don't understand how this i.e D[row].length; get the right length since row=0 at the start of the loop.

Comment: if an array is not equal I need to use the D[x].length in order to get the right count for the row BUT how does it get the right since xORrow starts at 0. Do you know what Im trying to say?

Comment: You're original code looked fine. Were you getting an error with it? There shouldn't an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

Comment: The first loop is the iteration each row as shown in my picture.  The second loop accesses the columns in each row. `D.length` is the vertical number of rows and `D[i].length` is the numbers of columns in row[i]

Comment: if the row/column are equal I don't need that extra addon under second loop ( j<D.length), it is only needed when he sides are not the same. My question is how does the j loop knows that the size is 5 not 6.

Comment: Yeah you don't need it if they are equal. But it's good practice to use D[i].length for a 2D array.

Comment: I just saw your edit. new String[5][6], makes 4 the max row index, that's why you are getting exception trying to access index 5;